# Change directory to the location of a file in find, then running a script two levels above (as if it was in the same dir) - bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

**The problem:**

Hi, I'm trying to loop over each *.faa file in multiple directories (e.g. /path/to/*.faa)

And then, using a script (./script.py) as if the script was in the same directory as the *.faa file, is this possible with shellscript?

**What I've tried:**

```
for FAA in $(find . -name "*.faa")
do
    cd ../$FAA
    python3 ../script.py
done
```

I've tried variations on this, but changing to the directory to a file doesn't work, but I don't know a way of getting to that directory.

**Desired output:**

For each .faa file, in multiple directories e.g /path/to/1.faa, path/2/2.faa,  run the script in the directory two levels above. As if it were in the same directory as each of the *.faa files, or if that's not possible, what is the best solution to achieving something similar?

Comment: You say "two levels above", but also "as in the same directory"? I'm not exactly sure what you mean, can you [edit] to add some sort of an example. E.g. if you `/some/path/to/foo.faa`, what directory do you want to go to run the script?

Comment: Do you mean you have `/some/path/script.py` that should be the one that runs for `/some/path/to/foo.faa`?

Comment: As you move around different directory depths, your relative path to `script.py` will need to change (`./` or `../` or `../../`, etc.). Can you provide an absolute path to the script please. (At least, an example one.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find . -type f -name '*.faa' -execdir python3 ../script.py ';'
```

This would execute `python3 ../script.py` with the directory of *each* found file as working directory.

Since your words and your code is somewhat conflicting, I'm not sure whether it should be `../script.py` or `../../script.py`.

Note too that this would only work if the `script.py` file is actually available in the indicated directory. It may be safer to provide an absolute path to the script file:

```
find . -type f -name '*.faa' -execdir python3 /path/to/script.py ';'
```

The above would execute the script for each found file, even if there are multiple `.faa` files in a directory.  To execute the script only once for each directory that has at least one `.faa` file in it:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c '
    for dir do
        set -- "$dir"/*.faa
        if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
            ( cd "$dir" && python3 /path/to/script.py )
        fi
    done' sh {} +
```

This would execute a short shell script for each found directory.  The script peeks into the directory to see if there are any `.faa` files in there.  If there is, the Python script is executed with that directory as working directory.

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)
- [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697)